# How does this site display this youtube video in overlay?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

I've been trying to understand what piece of code in the main.min.js file from this site [Meg](http://www.themeg.movie/files/js/main.min.js) inserts the youtube video as an iframe in the overlay.

```
<iframe id="auto-play-vid" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" title="YouTube video player" width="100%" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bsLk0NPRFAc?rel=0&amp;playsinline=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;controls=1&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;suggestedQuality=hd720&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Foutlawed-movie.test%3A8888&amp;widgetid=2"></iframe>
```

When I download the code the id="youtube-overlay" is empty it doesn't have an iframe with a youtube video in it. But when I open up the index.html file in the browser the video plays... Why and how is this done?

```
    </div>
    <div id="auto-play-close">
        <div class="back">
            <svg fill="#ffffff" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M19 6.41L17.59 5 12 10.59 6.41 5 5 6.41 10.59 12 5 17.59 6.41 19 12 13.41 17.59 19 19 17.59 13.41 12z" />
                <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="front">
            <svg fill="#c7ef00" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M19 6.41L17.59 5 12 10.59 6.41 5 5 6.41 10.59 12 5 17.59 6.41 19 12 13.41 17.59 19 19 17.59 13.41 12z" />
                <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    function e() {
        $("#youtube-overlay").css("display", "flex"),
        utilsController.checkYouTube() ? setTimeout(function() {
            t = function() {
                try {
                    n.pauseVideo()
                } catch (e) {}
            }
            ,
            s = function() {
                try {
                    n.playVideo()
                } catch (e) {}
            }
            ,
            h || _isIpad || ($(window).bind("focusout", t),
            $(window).bind("focusin", s)),
            $("#auto-play-close").on("click", function() {
                try {
                    n.destroy()
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e)
                }
                h || _isIpad || ($(window).unbind("focusout", t),
                $(window).unbind("focusin", s)),
                $("#youtube-overlay").css("display", "none"),
                v = !1,
                _ && b(),
                i && "true" === i && f()
            }),
            n = new YT.Player("auto-play-vid",{
                width: "100%",
                videoId: o,
                playerVars: {
                    rel: 0,
                    playsinline: 0,
                    autoplay: h || _isIpad ? 0 : 1,
                    controls: 1,
                    enablejsapi: 1,
                    showinfo: 0,
                    suggestedQuality: "hd720",
                    wmode: "transparent",
                    iv_load_policy: "3"
                },
                events: {
                    onReady: onPlayerReady,
                    onStateChange: function(e) {
                        e && 0 == e.data && ($("#youtube-overlay").css("display", "none"),
                        v = !1,
                        _ && b(),
                        f())
                    }
                }
            })
        }, 300) : setTimeout(e, 1e3)
    }()
}
```

This part switches the display property of a `#youtube-overly` div to `flex`(rather than `none`) when it's run (presumably on page load) to allow the div to take it's `fixed` position of `0,0,0,0` (i.e fixed at all four corners - read as: full screen) and show the `iframe` which is already in the div before the CSS change.

`onStateChange` switches it back to `none` and hides the div, after doing a few checks which are difficult to read from minified code.

**tldr; The iframe is in a 'hidden' div, which is 'shown' by the code snippet above (along with other stuff that aren't necessarily pertinent to the question)**

Comment: Thank you Nunicorn for the explanation, I did see that piece of code but when you do [link] (view-source:http://www.themeg.movie/) view source. there is no iframe with that video in the code. The only reason I was able to get that iframe snippet was by "inspecting" on the overlay video. It doesn't make sense to me :-(

Comment: For example I've downloaded the code and looked at the ```<div id="youtube-overlay">``` but there is no iframe with a youtube video inside it. I've edited my question with what it looks like so you can see.

Comment: It has something to do with this script [link](http://www.themeg.movie/files/vendor/vendor.js) I removed it and the video didn't display. I've never seen this before...

Comment: Which pulls in this code [link] (https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflcZyLnu/www-widgetapi.js)